# AngularJS service and mocked tests have conflicting context, when using own methods?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I have an AngularJS service which uses it's own methods (bad practice?). When I go to test this, and mock out the internally used method, I get conflicting context.

Here's an example service

```
angular.module('myModule', []).service('cardWarsService', function() {
    return {floopThePig:floopThePig,
            winAtCardWars:winAtCardWars};
    function winAtCardWars(cards){
      ....
      floopThePig(pigCard)
      ....
    };
    function floopThePig(card){
    // flooping happens here
    }
});
```

However when I try to mock out `floopThePig` I get told it's not called. This is how I'm mocking it.

```
spyOn(cardWarsService, 'floopThePig').and.callThrough();
```

If I change the call in the service to use `this` or with `var self = this` then it works in the test frame work but not in the application.

```
angular.module('myModule', []).service('cardWarsService', function() {
    var self = this;
    return {floopThePig:floopThePig,
            winAtCardWars:winAtCardWars};
    function winAtCardWars(cards){
      ....
      self.floopThePig(pigCard)
      ....
    };
    function floopThePig(card){
    // flooping happens here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Place your return object as a stand alone variable.

The issue is that the methods on either side of your return object are different. Your test only mocks the *interface*. As your application is not using the interface the spy doesn't pick up that it's being used.

This will guarantee our service will work in and out of the test framework

```
angular.module('myModule', []).service('cardWarsService', function() {
    var self = {floopThePig:floopThePig,
            winAtCardWars:winAtCardWars};
    return self;
    function winAtCardWars(cards){
      ....
      floopThePig(pigCard)
      ....
    };
    function floopThePig(card){
    // flooping happens here
    }
});
```